# call controller by timer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have to send query to remote program and recieve data. Then put them in my DB. 
This is possible to call controller's action every 60 seconds for example?

Thanks.

PS. I think it's must be done on server side. Not JS solution.

**UPDATE:**

First, I have MS SQL Server DB.
Second, There is remote program that listen specific TCP port and waiting a query.  I want to send a query every 60 seconds and parse response, then put parsed data in my MS SQL Server DB.

Comment: Please add a language tag to your question to ensure that it reaches the correct people that can help you.

Comment: Why can't you use JavaScript? That would be the natural way of pushing data from the browser.

Comment: suppose, on site enters 10 users. after 60 seconds will be 10 request to remote system. If no users on site?

Comment: This is a very confusing question. Is the data being computed or fetched from a database? Is the "DB" in question on the browser or on the server? Why do you want this to happen every 60 seconds? Is the "remote" program remote relative to the client, relative to the server, or both? Is the query being send directly from the client to the remote program, or via your server?

Comment: @user348173: Your comment is even more confusing. Is the fact that 10 requests will arrive every minute a problem? The phrase, "If no users on site?" is not even a question, despite the presence of a question mark.

Comment: Have you considered using SignalR? (http://signalr.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Using Ajax you could create a timer to send data to the controller every x seconds .
A spellchecker plugin in my web application does this , to do spell checking as you type .

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off using a standalone service (windows, wcf, msmq, etc) that runs in the background and "sends the query" and saves to your DB.

Web Applications are not designed to be utilized as time-based "always alive" mechanisms. "Timing" needs state, and HTTP is a stateless protocol.

Don't try to shoehorn functionality into something that isn't designed to handle it.

Then again i could be *completely* misunderstanding your question. Quite possible.

Confusing statements:

> This is possible to call controller's action

If it's external, how do you know it's a controller? Is this an external API?

> There is remote program that listen specific TCP port and waiting a query

That doesn't sound like a web application/controller.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cron on *nix base system. Or your program could trigger events every hours

```
0 * * * *  lynx url-of-your-program-address.com/action/to/call
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing. But since we are only here to guess at what you are on about here's a solution that might come close.

(P.S. I haven't compiled or tested this...because why should I care)

```
class ConsoleApplication
{
public static void Main()
{
  Timer myTimer = new Timer();
  myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler( DoAction );
  myTimer.Interval = 1000;
  myTimer.Start();

  while ( Console.Read() != 'q' )
  {
      ;    // do nothing...
  }
}

public static void DoAction( object source, ElapsedEventArgs e )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Made request at {0}", DateTime.Now);

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {               
        using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://whereever"))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how flexible your solution should be I would play around with Windows Service solution with Timer in it either with Quartz.Net.
You can find more details using the link below http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/